# Is there a list of all XSD of requests/responses available in eSignature REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a list of all XSD of requests/responses available in eSignature REST API ?

We need them for our integration efforts.

Comment: XSD is for XML, REST API (not SOAP) using json. Are you using REST or SOAP?

Comment: REST, Sir. Regards.

Comment: yes the list of all the endpoints is available , let me answer below

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the list of all requests and responses for the REST API can be found here:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference

Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Yep. I saw it. Thanks for sharing. But there aren't XSD schemas. Thus we need to generate them all by ourselves.

Comment: not sure what exactly you mean. XDS schema for what? this is REST API, it is not using XML.

Comment: in that case, would you mind marking this question as answered?